# How to call an event handler from another function in the same JS

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

I'm adding a new use case to a very complex LWC code base.

To simplify the use case... when user types more than 10 char in Comment, the Status should auto-change from New to Pitched.

[image]

The legacy code already has 2 functions:

- handleStatusChange(event) - when the User manually changes from New to Pitched, it goes through some very complex code
- handleCommentChange(event)

My question:
How do I call handleStatusChange(event) from handleCommentChange(event)?
It's confusing for me because handleStatusChange is set to listen for an event.
Is there a way to pass the event from handleCommentChange to handleStatusChange?

I'm not finding the documentation. If you could point to it, that would also be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to call one event handler from another.

Specific to your requirement, check if more than 10 characters are added in the comment, call the handleStatusChange() event handler to get the status updated as well as handle the status update logic.

HTML:

```html
  <lightning-textarea
    name="comments"
    label="Comments"
    onchange={handleCommentChange}
  ></lightning-textarea>

  <lightning-combobox
    name="status"
    label="Status"
    value={value}
    placeholder="Select Status"
    options={options}
    onchange={handleStatusChange}
  ></lightning-combobox>
```

Javascript:

```js
  value;

  get options() {
    return [
      { label: 'New', value: 'new' },
      { label: 'Pitched', value: 'pitched' }
    ];
  }

  handleCommentChange(event) {
    console.log(event.detail.value);
    const input = event.detail.value;
    if (input.length >= 10) {
      //input length more than 10
      //update status to pitched
      this.handleStatusChange({ detail: { value: 'pitched' } });
    }
  }

  handleStatusChange(event) {
    console.log(event.detail.value);
    this.value = event.detail.value;

    switch (this.value) {
      case 'new':
        //logic if value is new
        break;
      case 'pitched':
        //logic if value is pitched
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }
```